# SwiftUI - "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an issue with the coding for my app, where I want to be able to scan a QR and bring it to the next page through navigation link. Right now I am able to scan a QR code and get a link but that is not a necessary function for me. Below I attached my code and got the issue "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments", any advice or help would be appreciated :)

```
struct QRCodeScannerExampleView: View {
    @State private var isPresentingScanner = false
    @State private var scannedCode: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            if let code = scannedCode {
                //error below
                NavigationLink("Next page", destination: PageThree(scannedCode: code), isActive: .constant(true)).hidden()
            }

            Button("Scan Code") {
                isPresentingScanner = true
            }

            Text("Scan a QR code to begin")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingScanner) {
            CodeScannerView(codeTypes: [.qr]) { response in
                if case let .success(result) = response {
                    scannedCode = result.string
                    isPresentingScanner = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page Three Code

```css
import SwiftUI

struct PageThree: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct PageThree_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PageThree()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for `PageThree`?

Comment: Hi I just did, but it is the default hello world code

Answer (score 2):

You forgot property:

```
struct PageThree: View {
    var scannedCode: String = ""   // << here !!
    var body: some View {
        Text("Code: " + scannedCode)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! However I then get another error "Missing argument for parameter 'scannedCode' in call".                                                                               
   struct PageThree_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PageThree()
        //error above
    }
}

Comment: Just add default value for property or put something for test in Preview.

Answer (score 2):

You create your `PageThree` View in two ways, One with `scannedCode`  as a parameter, one with no params.

```
PageThree(scannedCode: code)
```

```
PageThree()
```

Meanwhile, you defined your view with no initialize parameters

```
struct PageThree: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

For your current definition, you only can use `PageThree()` to create your view. If you want to pass value while initializing,  change your view implementation and consistently using one kind of initializing method.

```
struct PageThree: View {
    var scannedCode: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(scannedCode)
    }
}
```

or

```
struct PageThree: View {
    private var scannedCode: String
    init(code: String) {
        scannedCode = code
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(scannedCode)
    }
}
```

This is basic OOP, consider to learn it well before jump-in to development.
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html